# Inverse Laplace transform of $e^{-\pi s}/(s^2+3)$

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

> Find the Inverse Laplace transform of $e^{-\pi s}/(s^2+3)$

Can anybody solve the above question please

Comment: I reformatted the question. Please make sure I did not change it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if $F(s) = \frac{1}{s^2+3}$ then $f(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sin(\sqrt{3}t)$.

Recall $\mathcal{L}^{-1}[e^{-as}F(s)](t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}[F(s)](t-a)u(t-a)=f(t-a)u(t-a)$.

Apply that theorem to your $F$ with $a=\pi$ to obtain $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sin(\sqrt{3}(t-\pi))u(t-\pi)$.